# Firebase Multi Level Database into tableview

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

How do I get data from a child deeper into a database that has an unknown name?

My example structure is below.

[image]

This code works (to get the snapshot data) but I am hardcoding the second child. I will not always know this value (**Bus 1**).

```
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let usersRef = ref.child("Trips").child("Bus 1")
    usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        for snap in snapshot.children {
            let userSnap = snap as! FIRDataSnapshot
            let uid = userSnap.key //the uid of each user
            let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String:AnyObject] //child data
            let personOn = userDict["getOn"] as! String
            print("key = \(uid) is at getOn = \(personOn)")
        } 
    })
```

This will print:

```
key = Stop 1 is at getOn = 3
key = Stop 2 is at getOn = 7
```

Should I be structuring this differently? Flatter?

Thanks and let me know of any questions.

This is a more preferable way as I have a class for TripDetails which goes into an array to load into the table. But again, I do not know what the second child's name is.

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Trips").child("Bus 1").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let trip = TripDetails()

            trip.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            self.trips.append(trip)


            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }
        print(snapshot)
    }, withCancel: nil)
```

Comment: Do you want all the stops for all the busses?

Comment: Well, I plan to populate the tableView with the busses. Then show the details in a detailsViewController with the Stop 1: GetOn/GetOff,  Stop 2: GetOn/GetOff  and other information. I could probably get that data after using the didSelectRowAt using the Bus 1 value.

Comment: You could just observe FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Trips") and save all the busses and stops info. Basically the same as your first query, just with one extra loop.

Comment: Are you able to answer the question using the code I posted above?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not super sure what data you want exactly. If all you want is all the data you can just do this.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Trips")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let enumerator = snapshot.children
    while let bus = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
        print("\(bus.key)")
        let enumerator = bus.children
        while let stop = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
            let stopDict = stop.value as? [String: Any]
            let uid = stop.key
            let personOn = stopDict?["getOn"] as? String
            print("key = \(uid) is at getOn = \(personOn)")
        }
    }
})
```